# error: no module named 'langdetect' when using argparse

Tags: python, module, argparse, detection

I'm writing a program where a user inputs the name of a text file and the text can be altered in multiple ways. In order to do that, I need to detect the language of the text and I've chosen langdetect for now because of its compatibility with spacy. On its own langdetect works just fine, but I need to use argparse to get user input and that's when the error arises.

I have installed langdetect via pip and did the following imports:

```
from langdetect import detect
import langdetect
```

When I try to use langdetect it runs perfectly fine this way:

```
lang1 = langdetect.detect("Hallo meine Freunde")
print(lang1)

lang2 = detect("What's up my guys")
print(lang2)
```

results

```
de
en
```

However, when I use argparse to run the code on a conditional argument, python throws the error 'No module named 'langdetect''

```
import argparse
from langdetect import detect
import langdetect

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-f", "--foo")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo:
    lang1 = langdetect.detect("Hallo meine Freunde")
    print(lang1)

    lang2 = detect("What's up my guys")
    print(lang2)
```

Run code via

```
python3 main.py -f
```

The expected outcome should be the same as in the example above.

I'm not sure why it works when run via PyCharm but not when implemented in argparse and called via the cmd. Otherwise argparse works fine as well, it's just the combination of argparse and langdetect giving me trouble.

Comment: It's likely that your PyCharm environment is set up such that it recognizes argparse and langdetect whereas your command line environment is not. Run the "pip list" command from the command line and see if it shows langdetect.

Comment: Yep, it shows that langdetect 1.0.9 is installed

Comment: I found out that it works if I run it via python rather than python3. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Right, that tells you it's installed in one environment but not the other. "pip list" shows what's installed in your current environment. One way to make sure you are installing in the environment you want is to make it explicit. For example, "python -m pip install langdetect" to make sure you are installing in the "python" environment. Or "python3 -m pip install langdetect" to install in the "python3" environment.

Comment: You're right! I'll be more specific with installation from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed your code on colab and it showed no errors.

[image: code snippet]

As I was going through the comments, you mentioned having Python and Python3. I guess it must be the case that you have langdetect installed in Python and not Python3. You should check the installed libraries using `pip list` or `pip3 list`. That should clear things up.

Hope this works!

Comment: Yep, this cleared everything up. I'll be more specific with installing modules from now on... thanks!